# How to create a custom icon on .html page instead of the default chrome or explorer icon?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a local web page and would like to have a custom icon for the page. For example if the page is food.html, instead of showing CHROME OR EXPLORER icon I would like to have food image as icon for food.html page.

Comment: take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon

Answer (score 3):

you must set a custom icon for any html page.Example, for food.html, you create an icon named food.ico, add it to head tag:

```
<head>
    <link rel="icon" href="food.ico">
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. Whatever you are talking about .ico works fine in browser tabs but I would like to have icon for the webpage itself, for example for a folder we can customize the icon instead of a regular folder icon.